# Color table row if button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to turn the whole row red in my table when clicked using javascript.

I have managed to turn single cells red with the below code but not the whole tr.
Also once the row is red im unable to turn it back to white.

```
var ie = document.all
var ns = document.getElementById && !ie
function rowclick(e) {
var obj = ns ? e.target : event.srcElement
if (obj.tagName=="TD") {
obj.style.background="red"
obj.onblur=function() {
obj.style.background="white"
}
}
}
```

Note that changing if `(obj.tagName=="TD") {` to `if (obj.tagName=="TR") {` does not work

Comment: you'll need a client side script for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function rowclick(e) {
  var obj = this
  if (obj.tagName == "TR") {
    if (obj.style.backgroundColor === "red")
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "white"
    else
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "red"
  }
}

$('table tr').click(rowclick)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr><td>hello</td><td>world</td></tr>
    <tr><td>hello</td><td>world</td></tr>
    <tr><td>hello</td><td>world</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Updated to toggle background color.

Comment: Hey don ... Looks great but I want to be able to highlight multiple rows

Comment: Oh, I see. Updated code to toggle background color.

Comment: just about there but for some reason only does every other row :S -> i added it here in live view for you http://mr-tipster.com/pages/newcard.php